# Python error clipping raster

Tags: qgis, python, raster, clip, error

I am trying to clip a raster with a vector layer mask (shapefile) using the clipper tool (gdal) but I've got the next error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\widgetPluginBase.py", line 88, in onFinished
            self.base.onFinished(exitCode, status)
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\dialogBase.py", line 208, in onFinished
            msg = unicode(self.process.readAllStandardError())
        UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 85: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Both layers are in the same coordinate reference system, so this is not the problem

Comment: Does your username contain non-ASCII characters (i.e. characters with accents or similar symbols)?

Comment: Where can I saw my username? I'm starting with Qgis..

Comment: I meant your Windows profile name (i.e. `C:/Users/your_user_name`).

Comment: Oh sorry. No, my Windows profile is only a word, without numbers and symbols

Comment: What about paths to both vector and raster files? I also experienced too long paths to produce errors. If paths are clean, try a short path such as `D:/`.